# Informatica- What is the result if the IIF condition is null?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

If my Informatica code looks like this:

```
IIF(foo,1,0)
```

and `foo = NULL`, what would the output be?

Sorry if the answer to this is to obvious or is in a reference somewhere, but I couldn't find anything useful through googling or searching SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a expression that should evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so here's how Integration Service interprets different integer values when they constitute the entire condition:

```
IIF(  -7, 1, 0)  ->  1
IIF(   0, 1, 0)  ->  0
IIF(NULL, 1, 0)  ->  0
IIF(   7, 1, 0)  ->  1
```

All negative or positive integers yield `TRUE`.
The values `0` or `NULL` give `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd attempt at rewriting this particular piece. Although its not incorrect, its best not to code like this.  wrap the "foo" around a isnull() if you suspect it to be such. Further, use an nvl equivalent and check for those values.  Conditional checks dealing with NULL are always expensive.